# Cannot match any routes. URL Segment Error in Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I working on app using nativescript where am trying to redirect to a url with function parameter. Below is my html code

```
<StackLayout col="1" orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center"  (tap) ="getPagebyId(pageItem.PageCode)" >
```

Below is my componenet.ts code where I have created a function to get the value of pageByid:

```
  getPagebyId(PageCode): void {

    uiHelper.showLoader();

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.router.navigate(["/createPage", PageCode]);
    }, 3000);
}
```

This is my module.ts code

```
    import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
    import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";

    import { PagesRoutingModule } from "./Pages-routing.module";
    import { PagesComponent } from "./Pages.component";
    import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            NativeScriptCommonModule,
            PagesRoutingModule,
            NativeScriptFormsModule
        ],
        declarations: [
            PagesComponent
        ],
        schemas: [
            NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
        ]
    })
    export class PagesModule { }
```

But when I tap to button, it showing me this error : Cannot match any routes. URL Segment Error

Any help?

Comment: Can you provide your app-routing.module.ts file?

Comment: I edited my code, see

Comment: But where are your routes? Please review the documentation, https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ng-framework-modules/routing

Comment: Can you show us what you have inside `PagesRoutingModule`?

Comment: This is my page routing module
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: PagesComponent }
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})

Comment: Exactly, you don't have any routes that matches `/createPage/:pagecode`. Please go through the official routing documentation of Angular to know more.